# Apache 2 2.4 with Ubuntu 14.04 "Not found"

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I've a strange problem with Apache 2.4 and Ubuntu 14.04

When I changed the port from 80 to 81 everythings works perfect, but if I changed it back to 80 I get an error message "Not found".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration *file 000-default.conf* (in folder /etc/apache2/sites-available I think), try to change **DocumentRoot** with :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Comment: My DocumentRoot is "/var/www/html/xxx/xxx/"

Comment: Is your port number already used by another process ? try command 'netstat -natup | grep LISTEN'  to check used ports.

Comment: No, no other process used Port 80 or 81 only Apache.